# how to convert Base 64 string to GIF in go

Tags: go, gif

I'm having trouble converting a base 64 string to gif
i have tried the following.

```
unbased, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(bs64)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Cannot decode b64")
    }
    var imgCoupon image.Image
    imgCoupon, err = gif.Decode(bytes.NewReader(unbased))

    var opt gif.Options
    opt.NumColors = 256
    var buff bytes.Buffer
    gif.Encode(&buff, imgCoupon, &opt)
```

but when i uploaded it in the GCP/google cloud storage the GIF doesn't animate.

this is how i upload.

```
sw := storageClient.Bucket(bucket).Object("test"+"_file"+".gif").NewWriter(ctx)

if _, err := io.Copy(sw, &buff); err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
        "message": err.Error(),
        "error":   true,
    })
    return
}
```

the result:

[image: result]

how it should be:

[image: should be]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with how it's being decoded. `gif.Decode` returns an `image.Image`, but [`gif.DecodeAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/gif/#DecodeAll) returns a `gif.GIF` type.

Similarly, `gif.EncodeAll` is used to write multiple frames.

This is the code that works for me:

```golang
unbased, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(bs64)
if err != nil {
    panic("Cannot decode b64")
}

// Use DecodeAll to load the data into a gif.GIF
imgCoupon, err := gif.DecodeAll(bytes.NewReader(unbased))
imgCoupon.LoopCount = 0

// EncodeAll to the buffer
var buff bytes.Buffer
gif.EncodeAll(&buff, imgCoupon)
```