# Convert gif image into base64 in GO

Tags: go, base64, udp, gif

I am trying to send a gif file over UDP in go, the simplest method I think is to convert the gif image into a base64 string and send it, but when I convert the file bytes into base64 it returns an empty string, I've tried the module "chilkat" with this code :

```golang
bd := chilkat.NewBinData()
success := bd.LoadFile(path.Join(folderPath, "final.gif"))
if success != true {
    panic("Fail!")
    bd.DisposeBinData()
    return
}
b64Data := *bd.GetEncoded("base64")
```

But its not working, if someone can help me

Comment: Tell us the import path for chilkat.  Describe what is not working: did you get a compilation error, a panic, bad data or something else?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68310534/how-to-convert-base-64-string-to-gif-in-go

Comment: The import i used for chilkat is `import "chilkat"` and the error I get is more than 100 lines and its only error like this : `undefined reference to `CkNtlm_userName`, `undefined reference to `CkNtlm_version'` ... Is there a better way to convert my gif into base64 ? Like without chilkat, cause when I compile my program chilkat takes really long to compile

Comment: @AminRashidbeigi As i Said, i am not trying to convert base64 string into a gif but i need to do the complete reverse thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was this:

```golang
var buff bytes.Buffer
gif.EncodeAll(&buff, &anim)
based := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(buff.Bytes())
```

But the base64 string was clearly too long to be sent in UDP,
so the solution to send it correctly is this:

```golang
encoded := recordScreenToGIF(seconds) // Record X seconds of screen, & convert the result into a base64 GIF
splited := SplitSubN(encoded, 10000) // Split "encoded" each 10K characters
conn.Write([]byte(strconv.Itoa(len(splited))))
for _, elm := range splited {
    _, err = conn.Write([]byte(elm))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
}
conn.Write([]byte("Done"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [encoding/base64](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/base64) package in the standard library.

You will most likely want to convert or append it into a `[]byte` slice that represents the UDP packet you want to send.

Here are some examples for encoding a file path or `io.Reader` into a `[]byte`:

```golang
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/base64"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func EncodePath(path string) ([]byte, error) {
    data, err := os.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    output := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(data)))
    base64.StdEncoding.Encode(output, data)
    return output, nil
}

func EncodeReader(rd io.Reader) ([]byte, error) {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    enc := base64.NewEncoder(base64.StdEncoding, &b)
    if _, err := io.Copy(enc, rd); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := enc.Close(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return b.Bytes(), nil
}
```